# Simple Linked List interchanging with next->next

Tags: c++, list, c++11, swap, singly-linked-list

I've bumped in a strange occurrence while I was trying to construct a interchange function for two nodes in a Simple Linked List.

A List with 5 nodes. I passed the first node, and the 3rd:

```
//list is the head of the linked list
interchange(list, list->pNext->pNext);
```

Below is the only instruction that causes the problem, to make it simpler:

```
void interchange(SList*& p, SList*& q) {
    p->pNext->pNext = q->pNext->pNext;
}
```

My problem is that, from my understanding of coding, the left member in an equal operations gets the value of the right member. p->pNext->pNext takes the correct value as it should. **But the pointer named "q" will point to q->pNext->pNext after this single instruction.**

Can someone brilliant shed some light on this?
Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: `p->pNext->pNext` isn't safe, as `p->pNext` can be NULL.

Comment: Draw it out on paper.

Comment: @David Zaberca Show the list definition.

Comment: Whenever you are tempted to describe a programming task as "simple", tell the rubber duck exactly who it is you are trying to fool. Linked lists are not simple. That's why we use `std::list` and `std::forward_list`.

Comment: `p->pNext->pNext` is the same object as `q`. If you don't pass `q` by reference its value will not change. Don't pass by reference as a matter of habit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the call to `interchange(SList*& p, SList*& q)`.

You pass it the value of `p = list` as a reference and its grandchild `q = list->pNext->pNext`, also as a reference.

When you assign `p->pNext->pNext` the value of `q->pNext->pNext`, you're modifying `list->pNext->pNext` to point to `list->pNext->pNext->pNext->pNext`.

Since `q = list->pNext->pNext` as a reference, you're also modifying `q` to point to `list->pNext->pNext->pNext->pNext`; `q` is after all, basically a renamed `list->pNext->pNext`.

If you change the function signature to `void interchange(SList* p, SList* q)` you will not modify `q`, since it's now just a basic pointer, when you change `p->pNext->pNext`.

Comment: Thank you for the good reply. So q is not retaining the address of list->pNext->pNext, it instead retains the process to get there. This is strange for me because, say if instead of SList*& I use SList**, I was expecting q to be and address which points to another address which points to SList. But q actually points to an instruction or an address of an instruction. Is this correct?

Comment: No. You could just think of a reference as being a new name for the same variable. You're not executing any instructions to access it in the function. If you use `SList**`, you're doing pretty much the same as `SList*&`, except you're now allowing `q` to be `nullptr`.

Comment: Ok. I get it. Reference is another name, when I use SList*& q I'm actually calling list->pNext->pNext. But if q is SList**, then *q is an address. If list->pNext->pNext is an address too, why is *q not the address? Can you recommend keywords to search youtube more into this specific subject?

Comment: `SList *& q` is a reference to a pointer; i.e. it aliases that pointer. `SList **q` is a pointer to a pointer -- in most cases this is pretty much the same, except you need to use `->` instead of `.` and `*q` instead of just plain `q' -- also you can change the value pointer to by `SList ** q`, whereas with `SList *& q` you cannot. For `SList ** q`, `q` contains an address.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic you currently have implemented

```
p = list
q = list->pNext->pNext

p->pNext->pNext = q->pNext->pNext
// Same as
list->pNext->pNext = list->pNext->pNext->pNext->pNext

// Before list->A->B->C->D
// After list->A->D
```

You replaced the pointer to B with a pointer to D. `q` still points to `list->pNext->pNext` which now points to D which was `list->pNext->pNext->pNext->pNext` before which was previously equivalent to `q->pNext->pNext`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I get what is happening now. But what I still don't understand is why q equals list->pNext->pNext and it doesn't 
equal the address it was first given first. If list->pNext->pNext is equal to 0x00f, why is q not 0x00f and instead goes through list->pNext->pNext again?

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the list definition nevertheless the function can look the following way

```
void interchange( SList*& p, SList*& q ) 
{
    std::swap( p, q );
    std::swap( p->next, q->next );
}
```

as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct SList
{
    int data;
    SList *next;
};

void push_front( SList * &head, int data )
{
    SList *tmp = new SList { data, head };
    head = tmp;
}

std::ostream & display( SList * &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( const SList *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << ' ';

    }

    return os;
}

void interchange( SList*& p, SList*& q ) 
{
    std::swap( p, q );
    std::swap( p->next, q->next );
}

int main() 
{
    SList *head = nullptr;
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; )
    {
        push_front( head, --i );
    }

    display( head ) << std::endl;

    interchange( head, head->next->next );  

    display( head ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
2 1 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I was actually trying to avoid std::swap to look more in-depth. :)

Comment: @DavidZaberca There is no problem to substitute std:;swap with a user-defined code.